# Alliance benefits?

Tags: spore

What are alliance benefits between me and another empire? So far my experience is:

That if they are attacked, I have to come and help (otherwise they claim it as "Failed Missions"). But when I am attacked, they don't do jack. When I want them to attack somebody, they say "They're happy to help their neighbor" (or something like that; while in alliance), but then, they request +100.000 sporebucks. Offcourse I could lean ship of my ally. But why would I? It cannot take care of mine problems, neither his own. They're weak and fast to kill. When they die, you get "negativized" relation with them.

So what's the deal. I have to wipe their ---, but they aren't helping me.

Answer (score 2):

They give you extra supplies and resources and like you said you can have them attack people. You might be able to request assistance from them also if you are attacked, its been a while since I played that. Very sure you get resources though.

Comment: Which resources? Resources can be achieved by "Trade Route" which delivers spice to my planet too.

Comment: Like I said its been a while so what I meant be resources is spices. They will randomly deliver spices to you based upon actions you complete with them and after a while you can even buy their planet from them.

Comment: It's actually what I meant. "Trade Route", you don't need alliance for it. Although it can help make an alliances because it increases positive relations.

Comment: Alright I got you now. Being their alliance will let you fly in their air space freely, do other actions without having them attack you, and possibly buy things cheaper if I am thinking correctly. Keeping them from attacking you is hugely important the deeper into space you get...

Comment: That's also not the case. I am blue/green "faced" with whole galaxy (except threatening weirdo that wants 50.000 Sporebucks). With non I am allied. I can fly in their space, steal their things from planet etc. .

Comment: Well then there aren't any other benefits, not sure what your looking for. They will trade spices with you in the trading route and eventually sell you their planet, lower prices, and not attack on landing/flying. Alliances in that game just help you obtain spices, not get attacked....you get the point lol

Answer (score 1):

Forming an alliance allows you to set up trade routes, have them attack other nations, and help defend you if you're attacked. You don't really need to help them at all; but when you're the only two nations left, they join with you meaning you only need to do half the work. (Assuming they don't get destroyed)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some benefits I can think of:

1. Alliances can be beneficial for gaining the badge "Diplomat" which can unlock  tools.
2. Recharging and repairing at an ally's base will be noticeably cheaper than recharging from an unknown alien's base, this can be useful if you are attacking or colonising planets far way from you other planets.
3. Improving your relationship with initially hostile planets can prevent them from attacking you.
4. You can set up trade routes with them, and purchase their base. I have noticed that in a trade route that picking up spice from a planet that is trading will give you some of the spice that the ally's planet produces. Trade routes also pave the way to buying their solar systems.
5. If you protect them from hostile aliens, or prevent ecodisasters, it will help you unlock the Body Guard and Eco-Hero badges.
6. Allies rated strength 4 or 5 (this score is derived from no. of colonies owned) can teach you their philosophy if you want to try a new philosophy or get the Split Personality badge.
7. If you decide to ally with the Grox (I don't recommend it) if you have a high enough relationship score, they may not immediately hate you and declare war.
8. Heck, it's not nice to not be alone in the galaxy